# How to know the reason of transaction's reversion in parity?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, parity, contract-debugging, revert-opcode

I am testing ERC20 USDT contract locally with parity. I imported contract to my private testnet and manually generated raw transaction that calls "transfer" method of contract. I send it to the node using **eth_sendTransaction**, but it's got reverted. I want to understand the reason of it. I tried to call **trace_replayTransaction** rpc method, here is the result:

```
curl
    --data '{
        "jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "method":"trace_replayTransaction",
        "params":[
            "0x9a6df75ffa10e229b5620cb1f2079da29b7a8cbe65535bf2e8a34ed1739f1d93",
            ["stateDiff"]
        ],
        "id":1
    }'
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    -X POST ip:port
```

The result:

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "result":{
        "output":"0x",
        "stateDiff":{
            "0x56507ba059a09b2cb64f6ec5c2aaf402184858da":{
                "balance":{
                    "*":{
                        "from":"0x42ae0",
                        "to":"0x3cf50"
                    }
                },
                "code":"=",
                "nonce":{
                    "*":{
                        "from":"0x2",
                        "to":"0x3"
                    }
                },
                "storage":{}
            },
            "0x5ed8cee6b63b1c6afce3ad7c92f4fd7e1b8fad9f":{
                "balance":{
                    "*":{
                        "from":"0x1314fb370629b3c366",
                        "to":"0x1314fb370629b41ef6"
                    }
                },
                "code":"=",
                "nonce":"=",
                "storage":{}
            }
        },
        "trace":[],
        "vmTrace":null
    },
    "id":1
}
```

As I can see, the output field is empty. I would be very gratefull if someone could tell me how to find out the reason for the tx reversion in parity.

**EDITED:**

**trace_replayTransaction** takes a hash of the transaction, not it's actual body. But I can also provide the exact tx too. Here it is:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "blockHash": "0x161d801c113352414c409ac35883739c41d910acefbcff52fa14e4afdf047eed",
    "blockNumber": "0xb1",
    "chainId": "0x21",
    "condition": null,
    "creates": null,
    "from": "0x56507ba059a09b2cb64f6ec5c2aaf402184858da",
    "gas": "0x13880",
    "gasPrice": "0x1",
    "hash": "0x9a6df75ffa10e229b5620cb1f2079da29b7a8cbe65535bf2e8a34ed1739f1d93",
    "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000807e09f9b439eeb7c7b3e2cfd52fc6775f33352c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fa",
    "nonce": "0x2",
    "publicKey": "0x497104220bd7241711ca8173314894414b7d4bbd5689f8642812f2a4d55e78ec1257eeff5ed7a001115a22a1f73ac04ea974966854d79dbdb52b0875f1d14388",
    "r": "0x3999c6dfcd91c70ebeedb844585851384ddc8e259b2b059cda5cdfc7faf51dd5",
    "raw": "0xf8a50201830138809475aa3ac9799770edd6db780302fcd55e5b2cdbb201b844a9059cbb000000000000000000000000807e09f9b439eeb7c7b3e2cfd52fc6775f33352c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fa65a03999c6dfcd91c70ebeedb844585851384ddc8e259b2b059cda5cdfc7faf51dd5a0011dcf406a22c916d63f01d4359c1869524f110732b1257a708261f14383258c",
    "s": "0x11dcf406a22c916d63f01d4359c1869524f110732b1257a708261f14383258c",
    "standardV": "0x0",
    "to": "0x75aa3ac9799770edd6db780302fcd55e5b2cdbb2",
    "transactionIndex": "0x1",
    "v": "0x65",
    "value": "0x1"
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

The arguments of USDT transfer are in input field.

- a9059cbb — hash of a trasnsfer method
- 000000000000000000000000807e09f9b439eeb7c7b3e2cfd52fc6775f33352c — padded destination address
- 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fa — padded amount that I want to transfer

Also, 0x75aa3ac9799770edd6db780302fcd55e5b2cdbb2 — addres of my local USDT contract

Comment: Please explain how exactly this raw transaction reflects a call to the `transfer` method of the contract, and what parameters are passed to that method (I guess that all of this is embedded in `0x9a6df75f...739f1d93`, so you probably need to explain how you've calculated this value).

Comment: Hi. I updated my question.